# dll in c++, WINDOWS deployment / dependency's (mingw-w64 )

Tags: c++, windows, dll, deployment, mingw

**Background:**
I'm programming a plugin (basically a dll) for an x64 application.
More specifically this x64 WIN application comes with a "plugin manager" (a dll) that loads and unloads 3rd party plugins (like mine).
My plugin is written in C++ and I decided to compile it with mingw-w64. As IDE I've choosen Code::Blocks.
I tried to avoid MS tools since later I need to deploy "the same" plugin on Linux and MAC (but that's another story lets focus on Windows for now).

**Challenge:**
There is one severe issue I can not resolve reliable with my knowledge/skill level, although I really worked hard in days of researches and tests: Dependency on WINDOWS dll's.
**I must assure that this plugin runs on all WINDOWS versions from 7 to 10 (x64 only however).**
**The shipment of MS redistributables should be avoided since not practical in this case.**
Apparently a static linking of the c-runtime library "MSVCRT.dll" seems to be neither allowed by copyright nor a reliable solution since there seam to be many different releases on the various WIN versions. Although Microsoft describes it as "known dll" I'm not sure which version is available where and which version is able to run on a certain Win version. And if a certain MSVCRT.dll runs, does it have enough "functionallity" for my plugin? (To high for me)

**The question:**
In your professional opinion what's is a reliable way to assure stability for my plugin on WINDOWS 7 to 10 (x64) in terms of Windows dll dependency's?
Are there other pitfalls I should worry about in the context of this dependency's on deployment.

**Additional info:**
Dependency walker_x64 (what a handy tool!) in this development stage of the plugin shows me dependency's on:

- KERNEL32.DLL
- MSVCRT.DLL (That's the guy I'm worried the most)
- PM_64.DLL (That's the plugin manager of the x64 application)

On my computer (Windows 7 x64), MSVCRT.DLL shows version 7.0.7601.17744, OK, works. But if the customer has, say, a Windows 10 machine, freshly installed (not many MS redistributable versions available), will it work reliably?

I know that similar questions have been discussed before, especially on the c-runtime library "MSVCRT.dll". Many of them before WIN10 however.
The newlib idea (http://sourceware.org/newlib/) for example, 6years ago.
Mingw-w64 ships with archives called: libmsvcrt.a / libmsvcrtXXX.a. Is there a way with those?

I've read all I could find but I have to admit that now I have more doubts and questions than answers... 
Your prefessional advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may rely on presence and stability of at least the following dynamic libraries: **kernel32.dll**, **msvcrt.dll**, **user32.dll**, **gdi32.dll**. They are system libraries, present in C:\Windows\System32\ folder after the clean OS installation, and created by Microsoft as user API to interact with OS. MinGW library *libmsvcrt.a* (as well as non-static MS libraries) have no actual processing code but are just wrappers to call these DLLs from system folder.

Comment: And those dll's have the same range of features I can rely on from Windows 7 to 10, right? Or could there be problems when I compile on Windows 7 with a certain dll version and the customer has Windows 10?
Thank you!

Comment: I'm asking because I had exactly that problem a year ago. Although that plugin at the end had many more dependencies. Some customers needed to install many MS redistributables to make it work. This time I want to do it right. Thank you meanwhile, Serge, appreciated!

Comment: @fcad3d, Sorry for the delay, I was far away from Internet last week. MS adds new functions to these DLLs with the release of new versions of Windows but tries to keep the functionality of existing functions. Also they release bugfixes. Sometimes (rarely) MS really deprecates the use of some functions and documents this in MSDN. For your case I can't guess what's the source of problem (this needs an investigation of what happens) but suppose that the problem wasn't in msvcrt.dll.